# Spring JPA entity mapping LocalDate and LocalDateTime field to Sql Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA and have mapped the following entity to H2 Database fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CORR_ID")
    private String corrId;


    @Column(name = "CB_DATE")
    private LocalDate cbDate;


    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private LocalDate createdDate;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

}

-- H2 DB Script
CREATE TABLE REQUEST
(

    ID            BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CORR_ID       CHAR(36)              NOT NULL,
    CB_DATE       DATE                  NOT NULL,
    ACTIVE        BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
    CREATED_DATE  DATE                  NOT NULL,
    LAST_UPDATED  DATETIME              NOT NULL
);
```

I am unsure if the following SQL Server column definitions will map correctly to Java. I have seen that `BIT` maps to `boolean` java type, However, I am unsure about `Date` & `DateTime` will be mapped correctly to `LocalDate` & `LocalDateTime` respectively.

```
--MS SQL SEVER SCRIPT
CREATE TABLE REQUEST
(

    ID            BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CORR_ID       CHAR(36)              NOT NULL,
    CB_DATE       DATE                  NOT NULL,
    ACTIVE        BIT DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
    CREATED_DATE  DATE                  NOT NULL,
    LAST_UPDATED  DATETIME              NOT NULL
);
```

Some clarity around this will be appreciated. Do I need to make any adjust to my Java code? Are my SQL server definitions ok?

I am doing conversion before saving  with JPA:

```
re.setIsActive(tt.isActive());
re.setCbDate(LocalDate.parse(tt.getCobDate()));
re.setCreatedDate(LocalDate.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the version of the SQL Server itself, the SQL Server JDBC Driver and the used Hibernate Dialect play here a role to determine what types are correct or acceptable on the SQL Server side.

That's too many variables to say something. I would let Hibernate create the table and see what it generates. You need to determine which SQL Server version(s) you have to support. Based on that i would choose the best dialect and JDBC Driver and then again see what Hibernate will generate with this setup and take this as the correct types.